# SqlAlchemy why does engine create more connection than "permitted"

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

**Situation**

I am migrating some code from pyodbc to SqlAlchemy. I noticed that during some tests I get more active connections than previously. Old pyodbc code keeps at 2 connections at most while the new SqlAlchemy reaches 7.

To check connections I just run a query from the db using SSMS while my tests are running.
I am using pyodbc==5.0.1 and SQLAlchemy==2.0.23, Windows 10.

**Goal**

I want to keep the number of connection to be 5 at most. I tried tinkering with `poolclass=NullPool`, `pool_size`, `max_overflow`, `pool_recycle`, `pool_timeout` etc but nothing works. How do I limit the number of connections below a certain number at all times?

Here's a rough example of Python my code

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": "Driver={ODBC Driver 17..."})
engine = sa.create_engine(
    connection_url,
    fast_executemany=fast_executemany,
    # poolclass=NullPool # this
    pool_size=1,         # or this
    max_overflow=2       # and this do not influence anything
)

def get_connection():
    global engine
    return engine.connect()
    
    # old code
    # return pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17...")


def sql_query(query, params):
    connection = get_connection()
    res = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection, params=params)
    connection.close()

    
def some_test_mock():
    res = sql_query("1")
    res = sql_query("2")
    res = sql_query("3")

    for i in range(2):
       for j in range(2):
           res = sql_query(f"{i} {j}")

    res = sql_query("4")
```

Query to check conenctions:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses with (nolock)
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
    and ecid=0
    and loginame = 'testsqluser'
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame

--the number of connections climb from 1,2,3 to 7
--previously it would climb and stay at 2
```

Comment: I see your SQLAlchemy code; what does your pyodbc code look like?

Comment: @Xedni, added to question. Basically, in `get_connection` `return pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17...")`

Comment: Are you running your Python code on Windows?

Comment: @GordThompson, win10. Will test on linux soon

Comment: Be aware that Windows' ODBC Driver Manager also pools "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" connections by default. For diagnostic purposes you could disable the Windows connection pool by launching odbcad32.exe, switching to the ["Connection Pooling" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBwcS.png), double-clicking the "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" driver and choosing ["Don't pool connections to this driver"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYB2s.png)

Comment: `pool_size` and `max_overflow` are not applicable to `NullPool`. These are the parameters of `QueuePool`. https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool

Comment: @YuriiMotov, I know that's why it's commented

Comment: @GordThompson, it helped. I disabled it and parameters such as pool_size, max_overflow etc started working as expected.  Can you post it as an answer so that I accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODBC Driver Manager on Windows has its own connection pool that drivers can opt-in to use, and Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server (e.g., "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server") have historically done so. So a SQLAlchemy application running on Windows may actually have two connection pools in play: SQLAlchemy's and Windows'.

If this causes undesirable behaviour then we can disable Windows' connection pool for a specific driver by launching the ODBC Administrator (odbcad32.exe), switching to the "Connection Pooling" tab

[image: pooling.png]

double-clicking the driver name, and choosing "Don't pool connections to this driver"

[image: no.png]